# Writing a WebAPI that scales to large volume conurrency scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, concurrency

I know it is a broad topic, but I am looking for the 101 here. What considerations should I put in mind while writing a simple web api service with a database involved, in order for it to scale up in the future handling high volume of concurrent users with no problems?

Comment: Make any code calling the database asynchronous.

Comment: Could you explain the benefits resulting for this? I suppose this prevents blocking one of the limited threads serving http requests in IIS making it unusable till task I finished, which results in fewer threads handling requests. Am I getting this right? or missing something?

Comment: Yes. It does not prevent thread starvation occurring, but it reduces the likelihood as IO bound calls will be non blocking.

Answer (score 0):

The main considerations I would have are (in brief):

1. **Error handling** - How you present errors from your API, and how you log these for future debugging
2. **Hosting choices** (and their ability to scale) - Modern cloud providers handling scaling exceptionally well. See Azure Cloud Service for example.
3. **Choice of ORM Provider** - As an example choosing Dapper over Entity Framework will give you performance benefits. Especially if you model your objects carefully.
4. **Caching** - Consider how often you need to call your database, what you can cache and also where you can cache it (for example Redis).